# Rational of why Paxos only issues new values if its value is the largest one in the majority that he can see?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, distributed-systems

I was studying Paxos from:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/paxos-simple.pdf

Recall that Paxos is a distributed system algorithm with the goal that the processes participating in its protocol will reach consensus on one of the valid values.

I was reading page 4 of the paper where it says condition $P2^c$:

"For any v and n, if a proposal with value v and number n is issued, then there is a set S consisting of a majority of acceptors such that

- (a) no acceptor in S has accepted any proposal numbered less than n, or
- (b) v is the value of the highest-numbered proposal among all proposals numbered less than n accepted by the acceptors in S."

(Where S = any set consisting of a majority of acceptors. 
C = the set of acceptors that have accepted some value c, the letter C stands for the majority that has Chosen a value).

I was trying to understand better the conditions for issuing a proposal, specifically (b) is the one causing troubles for me.

For me (a), makes sense because we don't want to issue a new proposal with a higher sequence number if there has been any proposal that has been chosen from the majority we are able to see (i.e. S). Since anything that has been chosen is accepted and since something chosen is part of the majority C, if we issue a new proposal, we could risk confusing the current paxos instance when its already chosen a value.

However, (b) is less clear to me why we want it to hold. Recall (b) is:

(b) = "v is the value of the highest-numbered proposal among all proposals numbered less than n accepted by the acceptors in S".

Why are we interested in having that condition? Which safety properties does that condition help us maintain?

---

Author: Leslie Lamport

Title: Paxos made simple

Institution: Microsoft Research

Comment: You have posted a number of questions on the same paper. Are you trying to outsource some kind of assignment? In any case, please format your posts more carefully. Shorter titles, appropriate tags and useful Markdown formatting go a long way towards making people read your questions.

Comment: No assignment. Just studying the papers.

Comment: I have put some time in thinking about to ask my questions and specially what title to put to them, if you have a specific suggestion on how to change it I would gladly change it! :)

Comment: Not specifically. It seems to me as if the titles make only sense to people who are familiar with "Paxos" (I am not) so you might restrict your readership. As for formatting, use Markdown for lists and links, that should help a lot. See [also here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/820/98).

Comment: This question is specifically about understanding "Paxos" (well known consensus distributed consensus algorithm). Its like asking a question about Dijistra's shortest path algorithm, if someone doesn't know what is is, its hard for them to help anyway. I am not sure how to make things better by removing the word Paxos (I am even inclined not remove the most important word form my question). Btw, if there would have been a tag labeled paxos, I would have used it. This question is only about distributed algorithms, not sure what additional tags would help or be related.

Comment: Also, if someone doesn't know what Paxos is, I provided the link to the turning award winner, Leslie Lamport's paper.

Comment: Also, I have used this site for some time, and I am aware that there is a homework tag. If it was some kind of homework I would have used it. I am just trying to understand paxos. Also, I feel kind of surprised no one has asked anything about such an important algorithm.

Comment: [There is no homework tag](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/468/homework-policy/470#470). As for the other points, feel free to do what you think is best.

Comment: Interesting, I guess thats a thing only in stack for CS. Its hard to remember all the rules for every single stack site :P, but thanks for that! I also feel that Paxos is a very important algorithm and I am sure that anyone else that ever reads that paper or tries to understand Paxos might have similar question, so I feel it will probably (I hope) help other people in the future :)

Comment: A question asking for Lamport's rationale is unanswerable (except by the author), and is inappropriate for SE. There's nothing to be said beyond repeating the paper: the invariant is utilized by the algorithm to guarantee the agreement condition of the consensus problem.

Answer (score 2):

The paper already gives a detailed explanation to motivate that condition and explain why it is useful to prove that a protocol meets that condition.  Read the development in Section 2 of the paper; it lays the chain of reasoning out very nicely.

To summarize: P2c helps us prove P2b; P2b helps us prove P1 and P2; P1 and P2 help us ensure that we meet the safety requirements outlined at the start of Section 2.1.

So, to answer your question "Which safety properties does that condition help us maintain?": that condition helps us maintain the three safety properties specified at the start of Section 2.1 of the paper (as the paper already explains).